# How can I make CakePHP not return views?

Tags: json, cakephp, view, controller

I am building an Android mobile application and for my server-side I am using CakePHP to respond with JSON objects. I have noticed that by default, CakePHP Controllers MUST have Views associated with them. How can I turn this off and instead simply just return the JSON objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

in the controller?
Its documented, by the way.

Also, there are special JsonViews for this exact use case. This view would not even try to look for view files.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#json-and-xml-views